# How to skip repetition in calling more than one variable in one line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

Hello guys I was wondering about how can I avoid repetition when calling multiple variables in the same line.

This was the code who made me wanna avoid repetition:

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
```

I really don't know but the only idea that came to my mind is using map? I really don't know please share some thoughts and help me!
Thank you!

Comment: a, b, c, d = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))
Thanks @chthonicdaemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a list instead of explicit names for your variables:

```
inputs_to_read = 4
inputs = [int(input()) for _ in range(inputs_to_read)]
```

Now you just have to reference your inputs by index rather than by name, so where you would have used `b` in your code further down you could use `inputs[0]`.

If the names are important you can use a dictionary:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
inputs = {name: int(input()) for name in names}
```

now you can use `inputs['a']` instead of using numbers.

Comment: Hi Chthonicdaemon,
Ummmm, first thanks for your answer!
I just wanna ask you if there's a better way than using for loops?

Comment: I think you have the two options of explicitly naming the variables or using the looping mechanisms in Python.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

you may use it like this:

a,b,c,d=int(input("enter a")),int(input("enter b")),int(input("enter c")),int(input("enter d"))

Comment: Hello ARYAN_BATRA,
I feel like you didn't change a thing from my code.. 
Thanks for help!